# ERDAS IMAGINE: Spatial Modeler Volume Change

Tags: erdas-imagine, spatial-modeler

Goal: sum of volume change of two DEM; time 1 - time 2

How to insert an AOI/query for certain area

How to get visual change of loss and gain?